# "Flutter/Dart Dio: 'The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>' error

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I'm trying to create a base model for dio but I'm getting these errors and I can't solve it can you help me

**Errors**

The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

Dead code.
Try removing the code, or fixing the code before it so that it can be reached.

**Network Manager File**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:mintsisv1/core/base/model/base_model.dart';
import 'package:mintsisv1/core/constants/service.dart';

class NetworkManager {
  NetworkManager._init() {
    final baseOptions = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: AppService.baseUrl,
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${AppService.apiToken}'},
    );
    _dio = Dio(baseOptions);
  }
  NetworkManager.init();
  static final NetworkManager _instance = NetworkManager.init();
  static NetworkManager get instance {
    return _instance;
  }

  late Dio _dio;
  Future dioGet<T extends BaseModel>(String path, T model) async {
    final response = await _dio.get(path);

    switch (response.statusCode) {
      case HttpStatus.ok:
        final responseBody = response.data;
        if (responseBody is List) {
          return responseBody.map((e) => model.fromJson(e)).toList();
        } else if (responseBody is Map<String, dynamic>) {
          return model.fromJson(responseBody);
        }
        return responseBody;
        break;
      default:
        throw Exception('Network Error');
    }
  }
}
```

**Base Model File**

```
abstract class BaseModel<T> {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();

  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json);
}
```

Comment: thanks for help. Do you any idea "break" because giving dead code error

Comment: starting from dart 3 and above there is no need to write break statement in the switch case blocks. 

Flutter team said that it was implemented like that previously as it was the standard common with other programming languages ... so you just remove the break statement, and it will be ok.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the type of e variable passed to the fromJson function is not defined so it is by default a dynamic you can solve this problem like this :

```
return responseBody.map((e) => model.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic> )).toList();
```

or this

```
return responseBody.map<Map<String, dynamic>>((e) => model.fromJson(e)).toList();
```